# How to Read Json Response In vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I want to read a data from Json Response But i am getting Difficulty to get the data.
i want to read this item from Json Response as Shown Below

period, fromDate, dueDate, totalInstallmentAmountForPeriod

Json Response

```
{
        "currency": {
        "decimalPlaces": 0,
        "inMultiplesOf": 1
    },
    "loanTermInDays": 92,
    "totalPrincipalDisbursed": 100000,
    "periods": [
        {
            "dueDate": [
                2022,
                7,
                8
            ],
            "principalDisbursed": 100000,
            "totalActualCostOfLoanForPeriod": 0
        },
        {
            "period": 1,
            "fromDate": [
                2022,
                7,
                8
            ],
            "dueDate": [
                2022,
                8,
                8
            ],
            "daysInPeriod": 31,
            "totalInstallmentAmountForPeriod": 36035
        },
        {
            "period": 2,
            "fromDate": [
                2022,
                8,
                8
            ],
            "dueDate": [
                2022,
                9,
                8
            ],
            "daysInPeriod": 31,
            "totalInstallmentAmountForPeriod": 36035
        }
    ],
    "mandatorySavings": [
        { "periodId": 0"expectedSavings": 10000.000}]
}
```

Comment: You can use the [Paste Special](https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/Paste-Special-a-less-well-known-feature-in-Visual-Studio) option to create a Class that you can then deserialize the json into.

Comment: @Anu6is but how can i achive this in vb.net

Comment: Here's another option: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid, it looks like there is a missing comma after mandatorySavings -> periodId and expectedSavings.

Visual Studio has a cool feature called Paste JSON as Classes that can be found under Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes. Using either Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json, you can tidy the classes up a little bit using decorators so that you can conform to .NET standard naming conventions while still serializing the JSON to the expected values. I also prefer to use IEnumerables over arrays, but the paste JSON as classes uses the latter.

This is how the class definitions would look tidied up a bit:

```vb
Public Class Rootobject
    <JsonProperty("currency")>
    Public Property Currency As Currency

    <JsonProperty("loanTermInDays")>
    Public Property LoanTermInDays As Integer

    <JsonProperty("totalPrincipalDisbursed")>
    Public Property TotalPrincipalDisbursed As Integer

    <JsonProperty("periods")>
    Public Property Periods As IEnumerable(Of Period)

    <JsonProperty("mandatorySavings")>
    Public Property MandatorySavings As IEnumerable(Of Mandatorysaving)

End Class

Public Class Currency

    <JsonProperty("decimalPlaces")>
    Public Property DecimalPlaces As Integer

    <JsonProperty("inMultiplesOf")>
    Public Property InMultiplesOf As Integer

End Class

Public Class Period

    <JsonProperty("dueDate")>
    Public Property DueDate As IEnumerable(Of Integer)

    <JsonProperty("principalDisbursed")>
    Public Property PrincipalDisbursed As Integer

    <JsonProperty("totalActualCostOfLoanForPeriod")>
    Public Property TotalActualCostOfLoanForPeriod As Integer

    <JsonProperty("period")>
    Public Property Period As Integer

    <JsonProperty("fromDate")>
    Public Property FromDate As IEnumerable(Of Integer)

    <JsonProperty("daysInPeriod")>
    Public Property DaysInPeriod As Integer

    <JsonProperty("totalInstallmentAmountForPeriod")>
    Public Property TotalInstallmentAmountForPeriod As Integer

End Class

Public Class Mandatorysaving

    <JsonProperty("periodId")>
    Public Property PeriodId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("expectedSavings")>
    Public Property ExpectedSavings As Integer

End Class
```

Now all you would need to do is use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to convert the JSON literal to an instance of your Rootobject class:

```vb
Dim conversion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(literal)
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eq88rV

Comment: how can i access this data it is in array
period, fromDate, dueDate, totalInstallmentAmountForPeriod.

Comment: @HuzefaSayed - how much experience do you have in VB.NET?